# how to force tor to use just Http(s) Not socks5

Tags: configuration, torsocks, https

A proxy supports only http(S), No socks5.

In other words,i want to configure Tor to use HTTP proxy, not an SOCKS  proxy.

Comment: You can use transparent proxy.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: You can use `tsocks` which redirects a program's tcp and udp traffic to a socks server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to chain some HTTP proxy to Tor's SOCKSPort. This is generally not recommended, it acts as another possible means of leaking DNS (the HTTP proxy may decide to resolve it and I think firefox, the last I heard, was doing it's resolves before making requests through the HTTP proxy).

Polipo and Privoxy seem to be two of the most popular for this purpose. Tor itself does not have a native means of providing an HTTP proxy, it will require third party software.

Comment: that's what i read, i want to be sure if there is no other solution than using a third party software.but i think its impossible im trying to use Privoxy now